# How to define app flow in flutter_driver automation testing?

Tags: flutter

How can I detect different screens and on the basis of it perform some testing. For example, If i am having a login screen in my app and if it's already signed in then different page may open after starting the app.How can I detect different screens and perform testing on it.
I am using flutter_driver for testing.

```
 test("Home", ()async{
      await driver.runUnsynchronized(() async {

        await driver.waitFor(find.text("login"));
        await driver.tap(find.text("login"));

      });


    });

    test("Game Results", ()async{
      await driver.runUnsynchronized(() async {
        await driver.waitFor(find.text("Configure your team for the next game"));
        await driver.scroll(find.text("success"), 0, -300, Duration(milliseconds: 500));

        await driver.tap(find.text("success"));


      });
```